# Do Turtles recognize their startpoint?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

If I have a Turtle exercising a program that causes it to move, does it know by nature the location where it started, or would I have to write a counter for each step it took so it knew how to get back?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Natively, **no,** a turtle does not remember its "starting" position. In order to implement this, you could do as you suggest and simply perform the reverse of the steps it took, however, that is not really restart-robust. Let's say you wanted to implement a home position for general use for a turtle (Wireless Turtles only).

The `GPS` API built into ComputerCraft can prove to be very useful here. It will allow you to write code to send a turtle to a specific set of coordinates, or to return its current XYZ position in the world.

To do this, you will need a Wireless Turtle, 4 Computers, 4 Wireless Modems, and some blocks to get up to build limit. The GPS host cluster works more effectively the higher up it is, so that is why we put it at the build limit.

Get yourself to build limit with your Computers, Wireless Modems, and blocks. I have found that this configuration works the best for a GPS host cluster.

[image: GPS Cluster Configuration]

On each computer's `startup` file, you are going to want to put the following code: `shell.run("gps","host",x,y,z)`, where `x,y,z` are the coordinates of the computer itself (be careful with the y-coordinate; if your feet position while standing on the computer is 256, the computer itself is actually at 255). For more info on setting up a GPS host, check out [this guide](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/3088-how-to-guide-gps-global-position-system/) on the ComputerCraft forums.

So now you have a GPS satellite. Now what? You can use the GPS API in your programs to figure out the turtle's coordinates as follows:

```
x, y, z = gps.locate()
if x == nil then
   print("Location not found")
else
   print(x," ",y," ",z)
end
```

From there, use those coordinates as you see fit to build your programs.

Now, is this a bit overkill for this purpose? Probably. But there are numerous other reasons to want a "home position", and for larger projects, having a `moveto` function to call upon is really handy.

Answer (score 1):

Turtles of no way of knowing where they've been by default, only where they are going. you can code a backtrack method that just reverses the commands if was given. See the [Full API](http://computercraft.info/wiki/index.php?title=Turtle_%28API%29) for help on how to do it.